# Can I applyBindings to more than one DOM element using Knockout?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I've got a structure like this:

```
<div id='col1'> ... some ko elements ... </div>
<div id='col2'></div>
<div id='col3'> ... some more ko elements ... </div>
```

... and I need to be able to `ko.applyBindings` to `col1` and `col3`. Right now, I'm doing something like this to bind to `col1`:

```
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById("col1"));
```

That works fine to populate the first column. But I still lack the third column. I'd love to be able to do this:

```
<div id='col1' class='bindable'> ... some ko elements ... </div>
<div id='col2'></div>
<div id='col3' class='bindable'> ... some more ko elements ... </div>
```

And then...

```
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, $(".bindable"));
```

... so that it attempts to bind to all instances of `.bindable`. Is there anything like this in knockout, or do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's the best solution I've found:

```
<div id='col1' class='bindable'> ... some ko elements ... </div>
<div id='col2'></div>
<div id='col3' class='bindable'> ... some more ko elements ... </div>
```

And then the script that binds...

```
$(".bindable").each(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, this[0]);
}
```

This works for me and it's nice and clean.

Comment: Only problem with this is that any code within the view models will be called for each element that has the bindable class.

Comment: Hm.. did not work for me but this did `$(".bindable").each(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(model1, $(this).get(0) )
} )`

Comment: with ko 2.3 I now get the error "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."

Comment: jQuery's `$.each` sets its callback's `this` to the `HTMLElement` not the jQuery wrapper object. So the line should be `ko.applyBindings( vm, this );`. @joelhoro you are unnecessarily wrapping and then unwrapping the element with `$(this).get(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this from another angle, you only have 1 view model. So why not wrap the entire set of div's (col1, col2, etc) with a div and bind your viewmodel to it?

```
<div id='myWrapper'>
    <div id='col1'> ... some ko elements ... </div>
    <div id='col2'></div>
    <div id='col3'> ... some more ko elements ... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is actually what I'm doing these days, especially after switching over to DurandalJS.

Comment: wouldn't it makes issues if you have bind data from an other view model in col2?