# Knockout JS bind view model to multiple distributed element IDs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is similar to my question, but it seems the solution is to create a common parent that is close by. In terms of commonality, the only way I could do that is to bind to `document` or something like that, but then it defeats the purpose:

[Can I applyBindings to more than one DOM element using Knockout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662743/can-i-applybindings-to-more-than-one-dom-element-using-knockout)

Is it recommended to bind a single view model instance to multiple IDs like this. I tried it, and it works in simple cases:

```
ko.applyBindings(newVm, document.getElementById('grapes'));
ko.applyBindings(newVm, document.getElementById('apples'));
```

My reasons for doing so is that I would like to use the built in functionality to bind to specific elements on a single page application, but those elements don't have a common parent.

When a binding is applied, are any copies of the view model instance created that would cause this to be a memory hog?

This is not about multiple view models to a single page view, and this is not about multiple view models to the same element. An example use case would be a `serverConnection` view model, where the connect and disconnect buttons are at the top in a toolbar, while the connection status is at the bottom in a status bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it recommended to bind a single view model instance to multiple IDs

No, it's not recommended. But also not necessarily wrong...

The recommended way is to use the `with` binding. For example:

#### JS

```
const serverConnection = new ServerConnection();
const app = new App();

ko.applyBindings({ app, serverConnection });
```

#### HTML

```
<body>
  <header data-bind="with: serverConnection">
    <button data-bind="click: connect">Connect</button>
    <button data-bind="click: disconnect">Disconnect</button>
  </header>

  <article data-bind="with: app">
    ...
  </article>

  <footer data-bind="with: serverConnection">
    <div data-bind="text: statusCode"></div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

#### Runnable snippet

```js
const serverConnection = new ServerConnection();
const app = new App(serverConnection);

ko.applyBindings({ app, serverConnection });


function App(connection) {
  this.user = connection.user;
  
  this.heading = ko.pureComputed(
    () => this.user() ? `Welcome, ${this.user()}` : `Connect to get started...`
  );
}

function ServerConnection() {
  this.connected = ko.observable(false);
  this.connecting = ko.observable(false);
  this.user = ko.observable(null);
  
  this.connect = () => {
    this.connecting(true);
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        this.connected(true);
        this.user("Jane Doe");
        this.connecting(false);
      },
      1500
    )
  };
  
  this.disconnect = () => {
    this.user(null);
    this.connected(false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<header data-bind="with: serverConnection">
  <button data-bind="click: connect, disable: connecting">Connect</button>
  <button data-bind="click: disconnect, disable: connecting">Disconnect</button>
</header>

<article data-bind="with: app">
  <h2 data-bind="text: heading"></h2>
</article>

<footer data-bind="with: serverConnection">
  <div data-bind="text: connected() ? '✅' : ''"></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. So the `with` binding scopes start at the global level, and I suppose you can nest them to get more specific? I think that's what I've been looking for for a while.

Comment: Exactly! You can read more about it in [the docs](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)